# I need help finding the short eruption clusters and long eruption clusters of a geyser using R studio

Tags: r

The question directs and ask this:

The eruption times for Old Faithful are clustered into two different groups. One group is short eruptions, and the other group is long eruptions.
Short eruptions last three minutes or less, while long eruptions last more than three minutes.
As below, define the vector e.times as:

e.times <- faithful$eruptions

Split the vector e.times into two vectors: a vector short that contains the times less than or equal to three minutes,
and a vector long that contains times greater than three minutes.
Answer the following questions:

How many elements are in the vector short?

How many elements are in the vector long?

What is the mean eruption time of the short eruptions?

What is the mean eruption time of the long eruptions?

What is the standard deviation of the short eruption times?

Comment: Some reason I can't get in contact with my Mentor to help me understand what it's asking.

Comment: There are general policies about [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) questions. Specifically, you should have made a good faith attempt to answer the question - can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is what I did:





library(datasets)





view(faithful$eruptions)





faithful




e.times <- faithful$eruptions




CountVector <- faithful$Eruptions 




ShortEruptions <- CountVector[CountVector <= 5]



LongEruptions <- CountVector[CountVector > 5]



length(ShortEruptions)




mean(short)



mean(long)

Comment: It would not let me edit my question since I don't have a 2,000 reputation

Comment: Never mind, I see it now. Thank you.

Comment: Your attempt looks correct, just instead of `<=5` shouldn't you use 3 ? You can use `mean` and `sd` function to calculate average and standard deviation respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I answered like this:

```
library(datasets)

faithful

eruption.time <- faithful$eruptions

eruption.time[eruption.time >= 3]

eruption.time[eruption.time <= 3]

mean(eruption.time <= 3)

mean(eruption.time >= 3)

sd(eruption.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it for the `short` vector. I'll let you adapt it for the long vector

```
library(datasets)

e_times <- faithful$eruptions

short <- e_times[e_times < 3]
mean_short <- mean(short)
sd_short <- sd(short)
```